# Using Gmail API's quickstart to authorize multiple times

Tags: go, command-line, gmail-api

I was using Gmail's Quickstart application to extract the labels from an email account, but I hoped that there was a way to change to code so that a login page would always show up. There's a one-time authorization, but I wanted to know if there was a way to prompt authorization every time I start the app. The code that I've been using can be found right here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/go

I will also attach the code below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/json"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
        "net/http"
        "os"

        "golang.org/x/net/context"
        "golang.org/x/oauth2"
        "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
        "google.golang.org/api/gmail/v1"
)

// Retrieve a token, saves the token, then returns the generated client.
func getClient(config *oauth2.Config) *http.Client {
        // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
        // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
        // time.
        tokFile := "token.json"
        tok, err := tokenFromFile(tokFile)
        if err != nil {
                tok = getTokenFromWeb(config)
                saveToken(tokFile, tok)
        }
        return config.Client(context.Background(), tok)
}

// Request a token from the web, then returns the retrieved token.
func getTokenFromWeb(config *oauth2.Config) *oauth2.Token {
        authURL := config.AuthCodeURL("state-token", oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
        fmt.Printf("Go to the following link in your browser then type the "+
                "authorization code: \n%v\n", authURL)

        var authCode string
        if _, err := fmt.Scan(&authCode); err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Unable to read authorization code: %v", err)
        }

        tok, err := config.Exchange(context.TODO(), authCode)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve token from web: %v", err)
        }
        return tok
}

// Retrieves a token from a local file.
func tokenFromFile(file string) (*oauth2.Token, error) {
        f, err := os.Open(file)
        if err != nil {
                return nil, err
        }
        defer f.Close()
        tok := &oauth2.Token{}
        err = json.NewDecoder(f).Decode(tok)
        return tok, err
}

// Saves a token to a file path.
func saveToken(path string, token *oauth2.Token) {
        fmt.Printf("Saving credential file to: %s\n", path)
        f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, 0600)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Unable to cache oauth token: %v", err)
        }
        defer f.Close()
        json.NewEncoder(f).Encode(token)
}

func main() {
        b, err := ioutil.ReadFile("credentials.json")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Unable to read client secret file: %v", err)
        }

        // If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved token.json.
        config, err := google.ConfigFromJSON(b, gmail.GmailReadonlyScope)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Unable to parse client secret file to config: %v", err)
        }
        client := getClient(config)

        srv, err := gmail.New(client)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve Gmail client: %v", err)
        }

        user := "me"
        r, err := srv.Users.Labels.List(user).Do()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatalf("Unable to retrieve labels: %v", err)
        }
        if len(r.Labels) == 0 {
                fmt.Println("No labels found.")
                return
        }
        fmt.Println("Labels:")
        for _, l := range r.Labels {
                fmt.Printf("- %s\n", l.Name)
        }
}
```

Comment: In your current script, when the file of `token.json` is not existing, the URL for retrieving the authorization code is displayed to the terminal. When the code is retrieved using the browser and it is inputted to the terminal, the refresh token and access token are saved to the file of `token.json`. For this situation, when you want to display the URL every time, how about removing `saveToken(tokFile, tok)` in the function of `getClient()`? By this, the refresh token and access token are not saved, and the URL is displayed every time. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: I got what you were saying, and I realized that the issue was exactly what you talked about. I also moved the token.json file out of the directory and was able to trigger the authorization page showing up. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post the resolved script by including the explanation as an answer and accept it? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Got locked out of my account, so here's what I did.

First, on the main method, I added:

```
if exists("token.json") {
    os.Remove("token.json")
}
```

Then, I made that method:

```
func exists(filename string) bool {
    info, err := os.Stat(filename)
    if os.IsNotExist(err) {
        return false
    }
    return !info.IsDir()
}
```